# Composer require | You must be using the interactive console to authenticate

Tags: magento-2.1, composer

I'm trying to run a `composer require worldpay/magento2-module-payments` on **Magento ver 2.1.8** and get this error:

```
[http]$ composer require worldpay/magento2-module-payments

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json' URL required authentication.
  You must be using the interactive console to authenticate
```

In Magento [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/web/install-web-sample-data-composer.html) I read that I need run this: `composer update`, however, I get the same error. It starts to load the repositories and then  throw the error again:

```
[http]$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json' URL required authentication.
  You must be using the interactive console to authenticate
```

Anyone had a similar problem or know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out that I was using a wrapper mage-run rather than composer it self. I have to specify PHP version and binary of the composer to use it.

I could either, make sure the credentials are present in the `composer.json` file or run the composer specifying the PHP version and composer binary: `php-7.0 /usr/local/bin/composer require worldpay/magento2-module-payments` it it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

What is your **Command-line Environment**? The problem may be caused by your Command-line Environment **is not interactive**.

I have never met the problem like you. I use the **CentOS 7 via putty**, when I `composer require`, it will ask my Magento authentication, input it and the composer will work.

Comment: I'm using **Debian 6.0.8 via PuTTY**,  I never came across this before either... Not sure what it's caused by and how to solve it.

Comment: @BareFeet Have you upgraded your Magento version recently? Maybe your upgrade is not complete, and lead some files broken, please retry upgrade by the official guide http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: It almost a fresh Magento 2.1.8 install, I haven't upgraded. Also, how can I check if the CMD line **is interactive**?

Comment: @BareFeet Because you use Debian 6.0.8 via PuTTY, so the problem should not be caused by interactive environment, maybe some interactive scripts file is  broken. Check CMD line is interactive: when you run `sudo` command, whether it will prompt you input password.

Comment: I get: `[http]$ sudo -bash: sudo: command not found` but when I run `su -l root` I get prompted with a password.

Comment: @BareFeet Strange! Please check this Q&A [-bash: sudo: command not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354928/bash-sudo-command-not-found).  Upvote your question and hope others could give a advice too.

Comment: thank you for all the advice! Will see how it all goes.